# Accessing object of another class in c# Ninjatrader

Tags: c#, class

I have a question regarding class object in C# in Ninjatrader.
To begin with, I am trying to build the class that will managed  the MACD indicator and method that will return true value if certain conditions are met. Now, I declare my class inside the strategy class(at the bottom):

```
private class MACD_test: MACD{

        public MACD_test(){

        }
        public int down(){
            Print(MACD(14, 28, 10).Diff[0]);
            Print(MACD(14, 28, 10)[0]);
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

It is just a simplifid example, but my problem is the line:

```
Print(MACD(14, 28, 10).Diff[0])
```

where I refer to macd method Diff. I am getting an error: Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Wierd thing is that I can refer to Macd value in the line below without an error:

```
Print(MACD(14, 28, 10)[0]);
```

Now, I thought that this is some kind of inheritance issue but after researching the topic for a while I didn't find any working answer. I udnerstand that MACD is also a class, but as far as I know it doesn't need cosntructor. 
I am not very fluent in C# so I would appreciate your help on how to access: MACD(14, 28, 10).Diff

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You would need to initialize an object of the class with `new MACD();`

The `Diff` method is not static, and thus won't be able to be called without an instance of the class `MACD`